# Mongodb find data from nested document

Tags: java, mongodb, nested

I have a document structure like this in collection 'mycoll' :

```
{
"orderid" : "123",
    "products" : {
        "1" : [ 
            {
                "pId" : "1",
               "name":"first prod"
            }
        ],
         "5" : [ 
            {
                "pId" : "5",
               "name":"fifth prod"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I want to find orderid across all the documents where products.name is like 'fifth'. please help me with the mongo query?

Comment: I have tried with db.getCollection('mycoll').find({'products.name':'fifth prod'}) , just to see if its exactly matching the records but this is not returning any output.

Comment: Your structure is flawed. You probably really want to store instead as `"products": [{ "pid": "1", "name": "first prod" },{ "pId": "5", "name": "fifth prod" }]`. So you either stored how you have in error or without understanding the limitation. Altering the path with named keys is not recommended and is not efficient for databases. Make consistent paths which are simple to query instead.

Answer (score 0):

> db.getCollection('mycoll').find({products: {$elemMatch: {name:'fifth prod'}}})

$elemMatch allows you to match more than one component within the same array element.

Further if you want to have the behaviour of **like** you can go ahead and use the regex/pattern inside the forward and backward slash. /.../

Comment: this doesn't works for me.

Comment: @veena is it possible for you to have the schema changes as suggested by Neil in above comments. The reason being above query failure is the path access way to arrays which is keyed in your case wouldn't work. Try to make the keys as part of the array elements field.